# identifier issue in this oracle subquery code?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, alm

What is wrong with this query ? I get an identifier  error at data.RN_RUN_ID.
The error is attached here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdZMM.jpg

```
ORA-00904: "STP"."ST_RUN_ID": invalid identifier
```

I am trying to run this query in ALM(Application Lifecycle Management) Dashboard module. Can't we use the actual column name if we have created alias for a column or is it just because I am using aggregate function in that column?

```
Select
        data.CF_ITEM_ID as"Test set folder ID" ,
        data.CF_Item_name as "Test Set folder name"  ,
        data.CF_Father_ID,
        data.CY_CYCLE_ID as "Test Set ID",
        data.CY_CYCLE as "Test Set Name" ,
        data.TC_TEST_ID as "Test ID",
        data.TS_Name as "Test Case Name",
        data.RN_RUN_ID as "Last RUN ID" ,
        data.RN_Status as "Last Run Status",
        data.RN_Execution_Date as "Run Execution Date",
        data.RN_Execution_Time as "Run Execution Time" ,
        stp.ST_Actual as "ST Actual" ,
        stp.ST_Expected as "ST Expected" ,
        stp.ST_Description as "ST Description" ,
        stp.ST_Status as "Step Status"
        FROM (SELECT  CF_ITEM_ID as"Test set folder ID" ,
        CF_Item_name as "Test Set folder name"  ,
        CF_Father_ID,
        CY_CYCLE_ID as "Test Set ID",
        CY_CYCLE as "Test Set Name" ,
        TC_TEST_ID as "Test ID",
        TS_Name as "Test Case Name",
        MAX(RN_RUN_ID) as "Last RUN ID" ,
        RN_Status as "Last Run Status",
        RN_Execution_Date as "Run Execution Date",
        RN_Execution_Time as "Run Execution Time"
        from  CYCL_FOLD 
       Inner Join   CYCLE ON   CF_ITEM_ID = CY_FOLDER_ID
       Inner join TESTCYCL on CY_CYCLE_ID = TC_CYCLE_ID
       Inner join   TEST on TC_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID
       Inner Join RUN on  TC_TEST_ID = RN_TEST_ID
       group by CF_Father_ID ,CF_ITEM_ID ,CF_Item_name,CY_CYCLE_ID, 
       CY_CYCLE,TC_TEST_ID,TS_Name,
       RN_Status,RN_Execution_Date,RN_Execution_Time) As data ,  (Select  ST_Actual as "ST Actual" ,
        ST_Expected as "ST Expected" ,
        ST_Description as "ST Description" ,
        ST_Status as "Step Status" from step )  As  stp where data.RN_RUN_ID = stp.ST_RUN_ID
```

Comment: Please show us the structure of the tables, ideally as create statements. And remove line by line of your query while it still produces the error.

Comment: I have already added "ST_RUN_ID" in select clause in my "stp" table but still getting the same error.

Comment: here is the link where you can see the table structure:https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.55/api_refs/project_db/webframe.html#topic1.html

Comment: You still need to slim down the query to help us analyze it. For instance, all the column aliases, for instance `as"Test set folder ID"` are neccessary for your application, but distract us from what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that's way too much information for me to read...

Comment: Please have a look around the [site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)) how questions are asked so you'll receive many answers.

Comment: You are using column aliases (with quoted identifiers....) in your inline views, but you're still trying to refer to the actual column names instead of those aliases in the outer query. You said you added the missing column used in the join condition; did you alias that too? Or has the error actually changed to refer to a different identifier?

Comment: Hey Alex, No I have not aliased that missing column . After adding that column the error is on data.RN_RUN_ID. And I guess you got my question correctly. Yes as you said I am still using the actual field name in outer query instead of alias which I have created in inner query. Is it not allowed?

Comment: I am surprised that it's not failing due to the invalid `AS` keywords for the inline view aliases. In Oracle it's just `from (blah blah) data`, not `as data`.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the column `stp.ST_RUN_ID` does not exist in the subquery:

```
Select  ST_Actual as "ST Actual" ,
        ST_Expected as "ST Expected" ,
        ST_Description as "ST Description" ,
        ST_Status as "Step Status" from step ) As stp
```

It doesn't matter if the column `ST_RUN_ID` actually exists in the table itself. If you don't name it in the subquery it's not available.

Solution? Just add it, as in:

```
Select  ST_Actual as "ST Actual" ,
        ST_Expected as "ST Expected" ,
        ST_Description as "ST Description" ,
        ST_Status as "Step Status",
        ST_RUN_ID
     from step) As stp
```